# Hiding divs effectively

Tags: javascript, html

I made a form somewhere on an HTML page, but made its visibility hidden so that it wouldn't appear immediately.  I wanted to activate it through a button click, but then appear at where the button was clicked, so I set the "innerHTML" of the button div to that of the hidden form.  The form appears, but it won't allow me to enter any data into the fields (I'm assuming due to it being hidden somewhere else) so I'm wondering if there is a way around this? Or a better alternative?

Thanks

Comment: You should post your code, or better yet, a jsfiddle

Comment: Please provide your html

Comment: Consider simply using css `display:none` and `display:block` to hide and show. With jQuery you could even use its `fadeIn/Out` methods. In fact, with CSS3 you can hide and show content entirely without JavaScript.

Comment: Replacing the *button*'s `innerHTML` with a form would definitely not yield the results you're thinking about. The new button will look something like `<button><form>...</form></button>` or `<input><form>...</form></input>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the button with the form altogether. With jQuery, you could use [`replaceWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/):

```
$('#button').replaceWith($('#form').show());
```

Comment: But how that get around the hidden issue? Or would it not matter?

Comment: @Sam, well, show it when replacing the button with it. Updated answer.

Comment: Is this correct? $("#b2").replaceWith($("#f1").show()); assuming that the button is in a div "b2" and the form is in one "f1"?  I tried it but it did not replace.

Comment: @Sam, that should work, yes. If it doesn't, then there's something non-trivial that you're not including in the question. Please post your code.